# java: mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"

Tags: java, mysql, linux, docker

###### The phenomenon and background of the problem

Deploy springboot project into docker container, back up blog database in mysql container docker

###### Problem related code

```java
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("docker","exec","mysql","mysqldump","-h81.71.87.241","-P3306","-uroot","-proot","blog",">","/mnt/docker/backup/aaa.sql");
```

###### Running results and error contents

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

###### The result I want to achieve

Please advise how to solve this problem.

Comment: Redirect to a file using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)

Comment: Redirects are a feature of the shell, and when you use `ProcessBuilder` you are not using a shell.